# Apple ID Verification (iPod touch)

Tags: apple-id

I did not receive any verification email for my Apple ID. I already repeated the procedures more than twice. What am I going to do?

Comment: Is the email address correct, are you able to receive emails from other sources, did you look into your spam folder?

Answer (score 1):

Contact the iTunes Store, let them know you are trying to verify your account and are not receiving any email. Also make sure to mention [if you did] that you checked the spam/junk folder and that your email on the account is correct [make sure it is].

They will provide further assistance from there and they'll most likely be able to enable it for you with some verification information.

Comment: They still **need** verification via email. Else, in the future you end up with no password restore option for example plus very critical info is sent (example on other device) for example.

Comment: This comment was from 2012, of course things have changed since and yes **NOW** they need verification via email.